# jquery resize function not firing in Safari or Chrome on load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, resize

I have a jquery script which has a whole lot of functions that trigger continuously when the window is resized.
The resize functions are all triggered on : jQuery(window).load(function(){
by firing:

```
$(function(){
 $(window).resize(function(){
   // code goes in here
 $(window).resize();
});
```

there is one piece of code that calculates the dimensions of elements inside a div to calculate the final length of the parent element:

```
var vWidth = 0; 
    var accum_width = 0;
        $(".interior_container").each(function(){
            var this_interior = this;
            var accum_width = 0;
            $(this_interior).find('.scroller_image_box').each(function() {
               accum_width += $(this).width();
            });
            var contTitle = $(this_interior).find('.interior_titleSlate').width();
            var contFormula = accum_width + contTitle;
            vWidth += contFormula + 1;
        });
        $('.allContainers').width(vWidth + 10);
```

so this measures all the widths of all elements inside .interior_container then adds them together then progressively goes throughout all .interior_container divs and adds them together to get the width for .allContainers

I am able to get this working fine in firefox but it will not work in chrome or safari
The moment I do a window resize however it does what it needs to do immediately

What do I need to do to get them to fire in chrome and safari?

Comment: firefox fires the resize event whenever the window size changes. chrome and safari only fire it when the window size stops changing.

Comment: So I figure I need to try fire the code the moment the window loads, can you think of a reason why it doesn't work when I just include it in the standard window.ready code?

Comment: Ok, I got it working. I just had to write a separate function containing the .allContainers width formula and then call that function once the page was ready

Answer (score 0):

I do this and never had an issue. I normally `throttle` the resize events cause they can get pretty crazy.

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('resize', function(){
  // Some codes!
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: This is giving me the same result, it definitely works fine for everything else, its just the width calculation that is not being fired until i actually do a resize.

Comment: You're setting `accum_width = 0` for every iteration.

Comment: Thanks Bill I need to reset accum_width each time because that is being used to measure each .interior_container, which are all different due to varying numbers of images and sizes. I have it sorted now by calling a function (see above) but thanks for your suggestion to help throttle the resize events.